# Regex To Remove Spaces Between Newlines and Content

Tags: javascript, regex

So I want to remove any spaces that lay between a new line and content.

```
 this

  is
    some

  content
son

          best
  believe
```

Should turn into:

```
this

is
some

content
son

best
believe
```

I've tried doing something like this, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
string.replace(/^\s*/g, '');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multiline mode:

```
string = string.replace(/^\s*/gm, '');
```

This makes `^` match the beginning of each line instead of the whole string.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys!  Both pretty quick!  I'll accept yours since your rep is lower than @Barmar's, but thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do the following.

```
string.replace(/^ +/gm, '');
```

Regular expression:

```
^     the beginning of the string
 +    ' ' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
```

The `g` modifier means global, all matches.
The `m` modifier means multi-line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line.

See [example](http://www.regex101.com/r/pB7wW6)

Answer (score 1):

You need the `m` modifier so that `^` will match newlines rather than the beginning of the string:

```
string.replace(/^\s*/gm, '');
```